# Running a for loop in Python: first time it runs through properly, but rest of the runs do not run properly

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

So I have an equation that replaces a number in a column (in a csv file) according to whether it's larger or smaller than my 'cut off' number. And save the output value into a document. The first time runs properly and gives me the right values. The next few loops though, the output values are all 0. (instead of a mix of 1 and 0)

df is a long document of numbers from my csv file

```
d =  df_gsuvr # same name as previous
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

list = [1.18, 1.12, 1.083, 1, 0.83]
for number in list:
#evaluate the number under the 'y' column according to 'number'
    df['y'] = df.apply(lambda x: "1" if float(x['y']) > number else "0", axis=1)
    df.to_csv(f"{number}.csv", index = True, header = True)
```

I am not getting any error messages with the code. when it's done running it always says "Process finished with exit code 0" but the outputs in the 2-4th values in the list will create a document of 0s (indicating that all the numbers in the document are < 0.83 which is completely false)

Comment: Do you have an example of what data is in the csv file that this is being applied to?

Comment: The csv file data is all numbers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your first loop you modify your df file. After your first loop your column `df['y']` only contains 0 or 1. That's why you only have 0 after the first loop.

You could solve your problem by doing your operations on a temporary df. Here is what it could look like :

```
d =  df_gsuvr # same name as previous
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_temp = df.copy()

list = [1.18, 1.12, 1.083, 1, 0.83]
for number in list:
#evaluate the number under the 'y' column according to 'number'
    df_temp['y'] = df.apply(lambda x: "1" if float(x['y']) > number else "0", axis=1)
    df_temp.to_csv(f"{number}.csv", index = True, header = True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I used this and it worked perfectly! I really appreciate that you took time out of your day to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `apply` method differently. I created an example dataframe:

```
d =  [0.2, 1, 3] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=['A'])
```

which looks like this:

```
    A
0   0.2
1   1.0
2   3.0
```

So the results can be reproduced:

```
my_list = [1.18, 1.12, 1.083, 1, 0.83]
for number in my_list:
    #evaluate the number under the 'y' column according to 'number'
    df['y'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: 1 if float(x) > number else 0)
    df.to_csv(f"{number}.csv", index = True, header = True)
```

PS: you probably also want to use integers `1` and `0`, instead of strings `"1"` and `"0"`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution! I will definitely consider using integers instead of strings! :)